# Sync New User Account on CIAM/Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Our system contains two applications, A and B. Application A makes a series of REST API calls to application B which creates a user account and creates another entity data for the user account on application B. The user only can access application B.

Now, we are asked to create the user account on CIAM, centralized user management, instead. To my understanding, the user account data won't get into our system until the user signs in to our system the first time. That would break the workflow as We shall not wait for a user to sign in to our system, application B, to create another entity for the user account.

To my understanding, user data on CIAM would be connected to Azure AD and the sign-in process will go through Azure AD for all users.

Any work around for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Since the user that first signs into application B is creating his account in Azure AD B2C through the GUI of this application in the backend, as such I am considering. Because, in Azure AD B2C, the user creates his own account after he signs up by entering his details as asked using either his social account email id or creating a new one. But as per what you have asked, it is quite imperative that the user whose data you want in your system or Azure AD will either need to be entered already or synced while the user is signing up for the application B. Thus, you will need a script to export the user data from the Azure B2C tenant and import it into Azure AD/system.

•   Thus, to export the customer data from Azure AD B2C and to import it in Azure AD/system, please refer to the below documentation link which describes the steps on exporting the user data from Azure B2C.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-data#export-customer-data

The following link explains in detail about how to export the user data along with the extension attributes and other attributes using powershell script and similarly import the same in Azure AD.

https://blog.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7804

•   One more suggestion is that you can add the Azure AD tenant where you want to sync this user data from Azure B2C as an external identity in the same Azure AD B2C tenant. And create user IDs of specific users whom you want can login to Azure AD B2C account through their Azure AD user ID credentials. This would help you to manage the Azure AD B2C users’ data via the selected user IDs created in Azure AD. Also, these selected privileged users can also be bestowed upon the responsibility of exporting and importing other users in original Azure AD tenant. To do the above, please refer to the link below for more details: -

https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-azure-ad-b2c-to-azure-ad-via-the-b2c-custom-identity-provider-42fbc2832e32

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. The system is quite small. The company won't agree to put any more resources to resolve the issue. We have come up with an alternative workflow to work around the problem.